# Proper parsing of "respondeo dicendum quod"

Tags: medieval-latin, grammar-identification, aquinas

Anyone who has read the Scholastics, such as St. Thomas Aquinas, is familiar with the basic structure of an *articulus*: ([Here's an example.](http://www.corpusthomisticum.org/sth2022.html))

1. Objections ("videtur quod...")
2. Quote from authority ("sed contra est...")
3. Corpus ("respondeo dicendum quod...")
4. Response to objections ("ad primum ergo dicendum quod....")

I am curious about the proper parsing of "respondeo dicendum quod." Although it's not surprising to see *quod* used to begin indirect discourse, I'm especially curious about *dicendum*. What exactly is it? Here are some possibilities:

1. It is an accusative gerund, the object of *respondeo*.
2. It is a neuter singular nominative impersonal gerundive, i.e. *dicendum est quod*

Neither makes a whole ton of sense to my mind, although it's pretty obvious what a translation should look like. In fact, many translations seem to translate as if it were an ablative, e.g. "I respond by saying that..."

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For *dicendum*, it would be necessary to supply the ellipsis *est*, yielding *dicendum est*, a passive periphrastic construction. Altogether, the phrase *respondeo dicendum quod* would thus be translated into English as, “I respond: it must be said that...” Therefore, I would say *dicendum* is parsed as a neuter gender, singular number, nominative case, gerundive.

In other works, Aquinas uses the entire phrase «Respondeo dicendum **est** quod» quite frequently.<sup>1</sup>

For example:

[image]

---

### Footnotes

<sup>1</sup> I searched for the phrase «respondeo dicendum est quod» in the [Corpus Thomisticum search tool](http://www.corpusthomisticum.org/it/index.age), and it found “159 cases in 108 places.”

Comment: Great find about the parallel construction! I've seen some editions punctuated to favor this approach, e.g. "Respondeo: dicendum, quod..."

Comment: Without the ellipsis of *est* and with this kind of punctuation your analysis is correct. I also found it searching in the Corpus Thomisticum and I wonder why the punctuation differs according to the various cases: I therefore preferred to focus on the syntactical value of the phrase without punctuation quoted by brianpck.

Answer (score 7):

First of all, the use of the **accusative gerund**  without preposition isn't verifiable with certainty until medieval Latin (*LG* II § 203 p. 377), despite AALTO pp. 82-85 quotes some passages of archaic texts which could attest this use (for example Pl. *Asin.* 338: *iam devorandum censes*; Ter Phor. 457: *ego amplius deliberandum censeo*; CIL I 2 1759 pontem peilas faciendum coiravere).

On the contrary, suppose a **neuter singular nominative impersonal gerundive** should be excluded as it doesn't suit for the case we are examining.

We then should take into account the possibility of a **predicative gerundive**, a construction attested for a large number of verbs (such as *do, adduco, peto, rogo, concedo, defero, denoto, mitto, relinquo, suscipio, trado* and, most of all, *habeo*) in classical authors, although used by medieval authors only (mainly Alexander of Hales, Bonaventura and St. Thomas) with the verbs *respondeo* and *dico*  (vd. *LG* II § 202 [p. 372]).

Examples of this construction are:

- Ter. *Phorm.* 365: *agrum ... colendum habebat*;
- Varro *rust.* 1,13,2: *multi ... habent ... importandum*;
- Sen. *contr.* 2,7,1: *confitendum habeo ... me ... fuisse*.

We could add that in Italian the phrase "*rispondo dicendo che*" is a sort of syntactical unit used in [prose](https://books.google.it/books?id=5VTe_CAmf-4C&pg=PA78&lpg=PA78&dq=rispondo%20dicendo%20che&source=bl&ots=2AVUcLvwt7&sig=FogN6QU9XFddSAJy5tY8wedPiMI&hl=it&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwiu0caKr8bRAhXGbRQKHbGKBoUQ6AEIQTAJ#v=onepage&q=rispondo%20dicendo%20che&f=false) as in [every day language](http://palermo.gds.it/2015/02/08/salvini-a-palermo-orlando-rispondo-dicendo-che-la-nostra-e-citta-cosmopolita_309336/), and in that case the verb *dicendo* is predicative of *rispondo*.

So I would consider the verb *dicendum* a **predicative gerundive of *respondeo*** rather than an accusative gerund object of *respondeo* or a neuter singular nominative impersonal gerundive.

Bibliography:

- M. Leumann - J.B. Hofmann  A. Szantyr, *Lateinische Grammatik*, München 1972-1979 (LG).
- P. Aalto, *Untersuchungen über das lateinische Gerundium und Gerundivum*, Helsinki 1949 (AALTO).

Comment: I'm not sure if the Italian represents a parallel case (though judging by your name you might be a better judge!): isn't *dicendo* a present participle, e.g. "respondeo dicens"? If so, that is a different construction that may well be influenced by the Vulgate.

Comment: I'm having trouble distinguishing the "predicative gerundive" with verbs of saying from a normal acc + inf construction. If I understand your interpretation correctly, isn't this basically the same as, "respondeo dicendum [esse] quod..."?

Comment: (1) The Italian phrase quoted is just a mere example of a similar use of this word sequence which, as you said, may be influenced by the vulgate. (2) In the normal acc + inf construction the verb of the subordinate clause isn't necessairily a predicative of the governing verb, while in the case of predicative gerundive one verb expresses the other (Sen. *contr.* 10,2,4: *pugnandum habebam ... patri*)